# Convert character vector to data.frame after str_extract()

Tags: r, dataframe, character, stringr

I have a dataframe:

```
head(objeto)
                                                      Edital
1                          GOVERNO DO ESTADO DE MINAS GERAIS
2 SECRETARIA-GERAL DA GOVERNADORIA DO ESTADO DE MINAS GERAIS
3                         EDITAL DA CONCORRÊNCIA Nº 001/2012
4                                        EDITAL DE LICITAÇÃO
5                                  CONCORRÊNCIA Nº. 001/2012
6                                      TIPO: TÉCNICA E PREÇO
```

I want to find the regex "Objeto" in it, so:

```
regex.objeto <- "(?<=Objeto: )([^.]+)"
objeto <- str_extract(edital, regex.objeto)

objeto

[1] "CONTRATAÇÃO DE EMPRESA PARA A PRESTAÇÃO DE SERVIÇOS\", \"ESPECIALIZADOS DE AFERIÇÃO DO DESEMPENHO E DA QUALIDADE DA\", \"CONCESSIONÁRIA MINAS ARENA GESTÃO DE INSTALAÇÕES ESPORTIVAS\", \n\"S"
```

The result is a character vector, but I would like to have a dataframe, without these symbols `\", \`

I was thinking the result something like this:

```
"CONTRATAÇÃO DE EMPRESA PARA A PRESTAÇÃO DE SERVIÇOS ESPECIALIZADOS DE AFERIÇÃO DO DESEMPENHO E DA QUALIDADE DA"
```

Thank you all!

Comment: `df <- data.frame(objeto)`

Comment: `objeto` seems like a string of length 1. Can you add data using `dput(head(objeto))` ?

Comment: > dput(head(objeto))
"CONTRATAÇÃO DE EMPRESA PARA A PRESTAÇÃO DE SERVIÇOS\", \"ESPECIALIZADOS DE AFERIÇÃO DO DESEMPENHO E DA QUALIDADE DA\", \"CONCESSIONÁRIA MINAS ARENA GESTÃO DE INSTALAÇÕES ESPORTIVAS\", \n\"S"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `gsub` to remove double quotes from the string and `"\n"`.

```
objeto <- gsub('"|\n|,', '', objeto)
```

which returns :

```
objeto
#[1] "CONTRATAÇÃO DE EMPRESA PARA A PRESTAÇÃO DE SERVIÇOS ESPECIALIZADOS DE AFERIÇÃO DO DESEMPENHO E DA QUALIDADE DA CONCESSIONÁRIA MINAS ARENA GESTÃO DE INSTALAÇÕES ESPORTIVAS S"
```

This can also be written as :

```
objeto <- gsub('["\n,]', '', objeto)
```

Or using `str_remove_all` from `stringr` library

```
stringr::str_remove_all(objeto, '[\n",]')
```

which is a shortcut for `str_replace_all`

```
stringr::str_replace_all(objeto, '[\n",]', '')
```

Comment: It works! How can I have to remove the , (comma) too?

Comment: @BrunIjbh Updated the answer.